# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion

Why was this deleted?

Visible to 10k only: https://superuser.com/questions/74038/win7-wont-let-me-in-password-is-correct

I don't think it should be. The accepted answer is something that has happened to many of us.

> I have a small media keyboard, the FN lock was on. So letters became numbers. Found it out by trying the the on screen keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire question was low-quality, and also several years old...More up-to-date questions are around now, for the same type of problem.

Comment: Fair enough....

Comment: why not just mark it as a duplicate and close it? Why the need to delete it?